# Can a countably generated $\sigma$-algebra be generated by a countable partition?

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $\mathcal A := (A_n)$ be a countable collection of subsets of $X$. Let $B_0 := A_0$ and
$$
B_{n+1} :=A_{n+1} \setminus \bigcup_{j=0}^n A_j \quad \forall n.
$$

Then $\mathcal B := (B_n)$ is pairwise disjoint and $\mathcal B \subset \sigma(\mathcal A)$. I think we can not recover $\mathcal A$ from $\mathcal B$, so I guess it is possible that $\sigma(\mathcal B) \subsetneq \sigma(\mathcal A)$. However, I could not come up with a counter-example. Could you please provide one such example?

Comment: with $\sigma$ you mean the generated sigma algebra?

Comment: Well $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal B$ so by definition $\sigma(\mathcal B)\subset\sigma(\mathcal A)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Borel $\sigma-$ algebra of $\mathbb R$ is countably generated: Look at intervals with rational end-points. It is not generated by a countable partition. This is because if it is generated by countbaae  a partition $(P_i)$ then any mesurable real function on  it would be constant on each $P_i$ , so it would take only countable number of values.

Answer (score 1):

Take $A_0=\{0,1\}$, $A_1=\{1,2\}$, $A_n = \{n+1\}$ for every $n>1$. The generated sets $B_i$ are $B_0=\{0,1\}$, $B_1=\{2\}$, $B_n = \{n+1\}$ for every $n>1$.
You can check by yourself that $\{1\}$ is in the sigma algebra of the $A_i$, but not in the one of the $B_i$.